# Replace "+" Character From URL Passed Variable in 2nd Page Form Field

Tags: html, forms, get, urlencode

I have a form on a home page and am trying to pass the input field value to another page with client-side only use. Issue is, I'd like to re-display the passed value back into another form field prior to running the function, but I cannot seem to be able to replace "+" character using REGEX (would also like to keep spacing). Any idea how I can accomplish this without much control?

**1st Page Form:**

```
            <form id="dlrhpform" type="GET" action="/dealer-locator">
                <div id="hp-form-input">
                                <div style="padding-left:20px;">    
                                    <p>Enter address or zip code:</p>
                            <input style="float:left;" type="text" id="hpaddress" name="hpaddress"/>
                        </div>
            </div>
                <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('hpsubmitbtn','','/btn_go_on.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
                <input onClick="_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1'],['_trackEvent','Dealer Locator','Input Parameter', document.getElementById('hpaddress').value]);" style="position:relative; z-index:9999;" type="image" id="hpsubmitbtn" src="/btn_go.png" border="0" width="20" height="21" alt="hpsubmitbtn"/>

            </form>
```

**2nd Page Form:**

```
        <form name="user-location" id="user-location" method="post" action="#">
        <div id="form-input" name="form-input">
            <label for="address">Enter Address or Zip Code:</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" style="width:200px;"/>
        </div>
        <div id="submit-btn"><input name="fetch" type="image" src="/searchbutton.png" onclick="address.value=address.value.replace(/,/g,''); _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1'],['_trackEvent','Dealer Locator','Input Parameter', document.getElementById('address').value]);"/></div>
    </form>
```

**2nd Page Script:**

```
//Return Home Page Address From URL
var urladdress;

if(document.URL.indexOf("hpaddress") >= 0)
{
    function getParams()
    {
        var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
        parent.params = new Array();
        if (idx != -1) 
        {
            var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
            for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++)
            {
                nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                parent.params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
            }
        }
        return params;
    }
    params = getParams();
    urladdress = unescape(params["hpaddress"]);
}

window.onload = function()
{
    if(typeof urladdress !== 'undefined')
    {
        document.getElementById("address").value = urladdress;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScripts .replace? Something like StringWtihPluses.replace("+"," ") assuming that all of the plus signs are spaces.

Comment: @AaronMiler Yes, I try this but cannot seem to get it to replace globally. (+) Doesn't seem to be recognized by REGEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a little research, I found that the hard part of replacing a plus is the fact that the plus sign in regex is used to indicated that there is more regex to follow. The plus sign is used as an operator in javascript. However, it is possible to escape it and replace it as follows.

```
var myString = "this+that+this+that++andthis++";
myString = myString.replace(/\+/g, " ");
alert(myString);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response on this - worked like a charm.